# barcodebakery Simplest Hello barcode error

Tags: php, barcode, barcode-scanner, barcode-printing

I have the following code to display hello barcode, I am using PHP 7;

```
<?php
require('barcodegen.1d-php5.v5.2.1/class/BCGcode128.barcode.php');
require('barcodegen.1d-php5.v5.2.1/class/BCGDrawing.php');

$code = new BCGcode128();
$code->parse('Hello');

$drawing = new BCGDrawing();
$drawing->setBarcode($code);
$drawing->draw();
?>
```

But I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to BCGDrawing::__construct() must be an instance of BCGColor, none given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\700.php on line 8 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\barcodegen.1d-php5.v5.2.1\class\BCGDrawing.php:40 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\700.php(8): BCGDrawing->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\barcodegen.1d-php5.v5.2.1\class\BCGDrawing.php on line 40
```

I googled this error and no solution found!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can find the the constructor definition of the `BCGDrawing` class in its definition file:

```
public function __construct($filename = null, BCGColor $color)
```

Also, in the library zip you downloaded there's an html folder. In that folder there's a file named `image.php`, and in this file (line 74) there's this code:

```
$drawing = new BCGDrawing('', $color_white);
```

If you scroll a bit up (line 50) you'll see the following:

```
$color_white = new BCGColor(255, 255, 255);
```

**EDIT**

I looked at the sample included in the library and modified your code to make a working test:

```
require('barcodegen.1d-php5.v5.2.1/class/BCGcode128.barcode.php');
require('barcodegen.1d-php5.v5.2.1/class/BCGDrawing.php');

header('Content-Type: image/png');

$color_white = new BCGColor(255, 255, 255);

$code = new BCGcode128();
$code->parse('Hello');

$drawing = new BCGDrawing('', $color_white);
$drawing->setBarcode($code);

$drawing->draw();
$drawing->finish(BCGDrawing::IMG_FORMAT_PNG);
```

Comment: found the constructor, as well as image.php and particular lines. What should I do to fix my problem. I am new to this library. What are the purpose of html and class folders? I passed this to the constructor: $drawing = new BCGDrawing(255, 255, 255); But still not working.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand. But the generated barcode is not read. I checked using bcWebCam windows software and Zxing android app. Any idea?

Comment: Those reading softwares read other code128 barcods well. Here is the generated barcode size is small to recognize?

Comment: @AmaliPerera try adding `$code->setScale(2);` right before the `parse` call.